# segmentation fault in a simplistic shell

Tags: c, shell, history, handler, sigint

I am writing code for a simplistic c shell. It stores the history of the last 10 command. If 'r' is entered as a command, then it should run the most recent command from the history. Also, if 'r x' is entered, where 'x' is the first letter of the command to be executed from history, then it runs the most recent command that start with that letter.

I've run into an issue copying from the history to the inputBuffer; it gives a segmentation fault when I try to do it.

Here is the code (it's messy I've been trying a lot of different things in hopes of fixing it).
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50

#define buffer "Command History:\n"

char history[10][MAX_LINE];
int count = 0;
int caught = 0;
int ct =0;
int rFlag =0;

/**
* setup() reads in the next command line, separating it into distinct tokens
 * using whitespace as delimiters. setup() sets the args parameter as a 
 * null-terminated string.
 */

void shell(void);

void printHistory()
{
      int i;
  int j = 0;
  int hcount = count;

      for (i = 0; i<10;i++)
    {
      printf("%d. ", hcount);
      while (history[i][j] != '\n' && history[i][j] != '\0'){
      printf("%c", history[i][j]);
      j++;
    }
   printf("\n");
   j = 0;   

   hcount--;
   if (hcount ==  0)
    break;
   }


}   

/* the signal handler function */
void handle_SIGINT() 
{
  write(STDOUT_FILENO,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
  printHistory();
  printf("\nCOMMAND->");
  caught = 1;
}


void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[],int *background)
{
  int k;
  int length, /* # of characters in the command line */
    i,     /* loop index for accessing inputBuffer array */
    start;  /* index where beginning of next command parameter is */
  //ct     /* index of where to place the next parameter into args[] */

  ct = 0;

  printf("Setup");

  /* read what the user enters on the command line */
  if (rFlag!=1)
    {
  length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE); 
  rFlag = 0;
    }
   printf("buff=%i", strlen(inputBuffer));
  if (caught == 1)
{
  length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);
  caught = 0;
}

  if ((strcmp(inputBuffer,"r\n\0")!=0) && (strncmp(inputBuffer, "r x", 2)!=0))
    {
      for (i = 9;i>0; i--)
    {
      strcpy(history[i], history[i-1]);
    }
      strcpy(history[0],inputBuffer); //this works
      count++;
    }


start = -1;
 if (length == 0)
  exit(0);            /* ^d was entered, end of user command stream */
if (length < 0){ 
  perror("error reading the command\n");
  exit(-1);           /* terminate with error code of -1 */
}


  /* examine every character in the inputBuffer */

       printf("beforeCase");
for (i=0;i<length;i++) 
  {
switch (inputBuffer[i])
  {
  case ' ':
  case '\t' :               /* argument separators */
    if(start != -1)
      {
    args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];    /* set up pointer */
    ct++;
      }
    inputBuffer[i] = '\0'; /* add a null char; make a C string */
    start = -1;
    break;

  case '\n':                 /* should be the final char examined */
    if (start != -1){
      args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];     
      ct++;
    }
    inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
    args[ct] = NULL; /* no more arguments to this command */
    break;  

  default :             /* some other character */
    if (start == -1)
      start = i;
    if (inputBuffer[i] == '&'){
      *background  = 1;
      inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
    }
  } 
  }    

args[ct] = NULL; /* just in case the input line was > 80 */

}

int main(void)
{
  char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /* buffer to hold the command entered */
  int background;             /* equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
  char *args[MAX_LINE/+1];/* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */
  pid_t pid;
  char iBuffer2[MAX_LINE];
  int i;

  /* set up the signal handler */
  struct sigaction handler;
  handler.sa_handler = handle_SIGINT; 
  sigaction(SIGINT, &handler, NULL);
  while (1){            /* Program terminates normally inside setup */
   background = 0;
    printf("COMMAND->");
   fflush(0);
   setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);/* get next command */

   if ((strcmp(args[0],"r")==0) && (ct==1))
   {
    fflush(0);
  rFlag = 1;
  background = 0;
  printf("strlen=%i", strlen(history[0]));
  setup(history[0], args, &background);
  printf("AFTER");

}

if (strcmp(args[0],"exit")==0)break; //exits if args[0]=="exit"
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) { //Error Occured
  fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed");
  exit(-1);
}
else if (pid == 0) {//Child Process
  execvp(args[0], args); // Execute command in args
  printf("%s: Command not found.\n", args[0]); //If invalid command
  exit(0);
}
  else { // Parent Process
if (background == 0) { // case with No '&'
  wait(NULL);
}
  }
printf("\nFinish\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Did you even _try_ using GDB?

Comment: And did you try indenting the code?

Answer (score 2):

`catchsegv` can be used to create a stack trace when a program terminates with a segmentation fault. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/glibc.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use low level i/o then it is your responsibility to NUL terminate the data after doing a read() before doing any string operations on the data read.

```
length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE-1);
if (length > 0)
   inputBuffer[length] = '\0';
else
   inputBuffer[0] = '\0';
```

But read() is probably not what you want to be using in the first place, as you seem to be expecting to be given a line at a time. Try using fgets() instead.